# Xcode keyboard shortcut to find shortcuts

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Intellij you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to do a quick search for shorcuts.  Does Xcode have this feature? How can you determine a shortcut in Xcode other than asking the Google?

Comment: Preferences > Key Bindings?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  Was looking for a keyboard shortcut but that's more or less the same.   Go ahead and add an answer...

Comment: I don't think this is a Stack Overflow question. How to use the Xcode software as software is not a programming matter. It's more a SuperUser or AskDifferent question, I think.

Comment: @matt: Stack Overflow explicitly includes questions about programming tools as on topic. The [tag:xcode] tag isn't for questions about the programs one writes/builds using Xcode, it's about using Xcode itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matt points out ultimately Preferences / Key Bindings is what I'm after.  And the shortcut to get to Preferences is: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.